# MYSQL: Cannot Connect to Database Server en Mac

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo instalado mysql server y mysql workbench pero cuando entro al workbench y pongo la contraseña ,que se me dio cuando termine de instalar el mysql server, me aparece el siguiente cartel:

> Cannot Connect to Database Server
>
> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to
>   server at localhost:3306:   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)
>
> Please:
>
> 1 Check that mysql is running on server localhost
>
> 2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default,
>   but this can be changed)
>
> 3 Check the root has rights to connect to localhost from your address
>   (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from
>   which machines)
>
> 4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the
>   correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're
>   connecting from

Comment: ¿Puedes ver algo relativo a MySQL en `Preferencias del Sistema`? ¿Puedes revisar el estado del servidor MySQL allí? Si no lo ves es posible que el servidor MySQL no esté instalado. Puedes verificar si está instalado y donde escribiendo en la terminal: `type -a mysql`

Comment: Intenta correr mysql con el comando sudo. `sudo mysql-workbench`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba reiniciando MySQL:

> $ brew services restart mysql

Para más info. visita:
[robots.thoughtbot.com](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew)